# ARM ELF file in IDA Pro

Tags: pi-2, arm

I'm a student. And I'm going to study reverse engineering on Raspberry Pi 2 in IDA Pro. I have try disassembling ARM ELF file("start.elf"). But, Result was not accurated.

I think I selected wrong start address(0x0) or file was obfuscated.

Please tell me to solve the problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure start.elf is an ARM binary.  My understanding is it is a binary blob for the GPU (which boots the Pi).

I assumed the [VideoCore IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VideoCore) was not an ARM device.

---

EDITED TO ADD

From [rasperrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=778772#p778772)

> ... Look up a guy called Herman Hermitage who has developed a
>   disassembler and tools for dealing with the ELF files.
>   https://github.com/hermanhermitage